# How to Rotate some of the display but no them all with AMD Eyefinity

Tags: display, resolution, amd-radeon, eyefinity

We are installing a 3x2 videowall using the Eyefinity utility to make a Single Large Surface of 5760x2160 resolution, but the trouble is that the workers installed the top round row  inverted 180 degrees.

I'm aware that with Eyefinity all the display work as a single display, but we are really on trouble with this. Could exist the chance from catalyst or from another software to rotate only the top three display  180 degrees individually (each of them) keeping the Single Large Surface?

Our Configurations is
* 1x AMD Radeon VisionTek HD 7870 withsix mini display port outputs
* 6x Noblex TV Display
* Windows 10 Pro
* Intel Core i7 processor
* Gigabyte Motherboard

[image: reference photo]

Comment: What have you tried? Did you install AMD Catalyst and click around in Catalyst Control Center trying to set up Eyefinity? Can you try left and right-clicking everywhere to see if there are any options to rotate individual displays? The UI of Catalyst Control Center varies widely depending on the version you have. Also make sure you have the latest Crimson drivers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in fact AMD Catalyst doesn't allow to invert the screen after the monitor grouping phase, it disable that option after eyefinity applies. In the end we used Inmersive Display PRO to divide the SLS Screen and apply all the corrections individually. Greetings

Answer (score 2):

That should work with AMD Eyefinity, yes! The key is that you have to set the orientation of each monitor at the time when you create the "display group" in Eyefinity - you can't change the orientation after the fact.

You'll need a GPU that supports "mixed rotation" display groups.

The next difficulty is that the standard Eyefinity setup tool often does not give you the option to change orientation of monitors.

You will need to do the entire setup from the "Advanced Settings" GUI, only then does the "create new display group" procedure include steps to individually choose the orientation of each panel.

Use the Radeon Pro drivers, and don't use the latest ones (for some reason the functionality has been reduced). I know that ones from early 2017 worked, so start with e.g. 17.q4.1 and upgrade later if needed.

Right-click on desktop, then choose AMD "Advanced Settings".
Click "Create new display group".
Important: choose "Use a new arrangement"
Continue through the next steps, where it asks you to select each panel that will be included, and then choose layout you want (3x2). It will then launch into a non-Windows GUI across all the selected displays, identifying each one with a number, and ask you to click one by one to add the displays to the group.
After you select the last (of 6 in your case) displays, the next screen will let you adjust the rotation of each display individually: the options should be Landscape, Landscape (flipped), Portrait, Portrait (flipped). And it looks like you'll want to select Landscape (flipped) for some of yours. During this procedure, each panel has a small white triangle in one corner - namely in its logical (not necessarily physical) lower right corner. As you adjust the rotation setting for each one, the white triangle will jump accordingly, letting you confirm what the orientation is that Eyefinity sees for each panel. In your case, your goal will be to have the white triangles all appear in the lower right corner, from your own physical point of view.

After that come steps to confirm and fine-tune the relative alignment of the panels, and how to spread the desktop across them - in your case, with a uniform 3x2 panel, these steps can be skipped through quickly.

Here is an image demonstrating what happens [image: Photo of 3 by 1 Eyefinity flipped]